# Parsley.js validation with post

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation, parsley.js

I'm validating a form with the (excellently crafted) `Parsley.js` script, and there's one element I can't seem to get working.

When the user successfully fills out the form, I want two things to happen:

- The form posts to a website database.
- A success message gets displayed.

So here's my code as it stands:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // form
    var form = $('#formname');
    var success = $('.success');

    form.submit(function(){

        if($form.parsley('isValid') == true){
            $.post('https://www.xxxxx.custom.api.url', $(this).serialize(), function(){
                success.show(); $('input[type=text]').val('');
            },'json');
        }

        return false;
    });

});
```

If I remove the "if" line and its corresponding bracket, my two commands work perfectly -- the form information gets submitted, and the message displays.

But when I include the "if" line and its bracket, it doesn't.

I'm not the world's biggest expert on jQuery/Javascript/etc., so I'm sure I'm missing something obvious. Any ideas what's wrong with this line?

`if($form.parsley('isValid') == true){`

Thanks, everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to validate `form` and not `$form`.

`$form` is undefined in your example above.

Try `if(form.parsley('isValid') == true){}` and see if something good happens.

Best

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply, Guillaume! Weirdly, that still didn't work. I'm getting the same results: When I submit the form, those two actions still aren't happening.

Should I remove this line?

var form = $('#formname');

Also, is there any particular version of Parsley I should be calling? Right now I'm calling parsley.js, although I also found examples that used parsley.min.js.

Comment: Could you make a jsfiddle of your example?

Comment: Working on it. Thank you!

Comment: Guillaume, I don't think I can put this on jsFiddle because this form has some secret keys to a client's back-end. Sorry to waste your time, and thanks again!!!